# Is WPF with version 3.5 fits Windows7 and Windows8?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i am developing WPF application in visual studio and using .NET 3.5.
does the application fits Windows7 and Windows8 OS with no .NET framework additional installation?
do i need to add .NET 3.5 installation to setup project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7 .NET framework 3.5 is part of the operating system so all machines should have it.

In Windows 8 or windows 8.1 .NET framework 3.5 is NOT automatically installed (though all machines that are *upgraded* from win 7 -> win 8 should have it).

To run apps that require the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8 or later, you must enable version 3.5 on your computer. There are two ways you can do this: by installing or running an app that requires the .NET Framework 3.5 (that is, by installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on demand), or by enabling the .NET Framework 3.5 in Control Panel. Both options require an Internet connection.

If an app requires the .NET Framework 3.5, but doesn't find that version enabled on your computer, it displays a message box, either during installation, or when you run the app for the first time. In the message box, choose Install this feature to enable the .NET Framework 3.5.

The above require an internet connection. If this is not possible you will have to include the .exe files of .NET 3.5 in your distribution

however as MSDN states:

> The .NET Framework 4.5 and its point releases are backward-compatible
>   with apps that were built with earlier versions of the .NET Framework.
>   In other words, apps and components built with previous versions will
>   work without modification on the .NET Framework 4.5. However, by
>   default, apps run on the version of the common language runtime for
>   which they were developed, so you may have to provide a configuration
>   file to enable your app to run on the .NET Framework 4.5

So build your project for 3.5 and just deploy it to windows 8 machines. It should run, but its not the "best" environment for the app. The "best" would be to have .NET 3.5 installed.

Comment: thanks, is there any .NET framework that will work on both OS with no additional installation? i dont want to add it to installation since it is large file with ~60MB.

Comment: @user3719173: check this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx

Comment: @user3719173 as you can see windows 7 comes with 3.5 and windows 8 with 4.5 so there is no certaintly that 2 machines will have a common .net framework installed.

Comment: i developed the application in visual studio with .NET 3.5. when i changed it to .net 4.5 the application compiled and run with no problem. does it mean that it will work fine with Win7 and Win8?

Comment: @user3719173: Only if Windows 7 machine has 4.5 installed which they doesn't from vanilla install. I think you should go with the 4.5 and include installation for win7 machines..What is holding you back from doing this?